# SSL Cloudfront + EC2 + Wordpress through Bitnami

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

I am using Cloudfront in front my EC2 instance which is running my wordpress application that was launched through Bitnami.

I have registered a SSL cert through ACM and linked it to Cloudfront but am having trouble configuring the wordpress site to handle the assets correctly.

I am currently having the error of unsafe scripts being blocked on the site (all css and js) I have tried using the plugin Insecure content fixer but have had no luck.

Site is: www.acutefabrication.com.au

My cloudfront settings:

[image: origin]

[image: behaviour settings]

Comment: I believe you'll have to fix those resource URLs at the WordPress level. Have you gone through the plugin's steps listed here? https://ssl.webaware.net.au/ specifically the "run the test tool" step? It looks like there is a setting in that plugin specifically for when it is used behind Amazon CloudFront that you may need to enable. Also, you will need to clear your CloudFront cache after you make any settings changes in WordPress (and then wait a while for the cache to clear).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by modifying my wp-config file and adding the "s" to the http: in these two lines, that plus the plugin seemed to do the trick.

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/');
define('WP_HOME', 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/');
```